# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load from loader findLibrary returned null

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I use NDK in eclipse.

This is my NativeLib in java:

```
public class NativeLib {

public native String enCode(String src);

static {
    System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld");
}

public native String deCode(String src);
}
```

This is C source:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>

jstring Java_com_example_helloworld_NativeLib_enCode(JNIEnv* env,
    jobject thiz, jstring src) {
...
return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, result);
}

jstring Java_com_example_helloworld_NativeLib_deCode(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz,
    jstring src) {
...
return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, result);
}
```

My project run normally in android 4.2 but in android 4.3(Tablet ASUS K012) It get error like below

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load HelloWorld from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.helloworld-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.helloworld-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /system/lib/arm]]]: findLibrary returned null

Can anyone help me?

Comment: and what processor is inside this tablet? did you provide native library for this processor?

Comment: @Selvin I don't understand. I forgot that I use my library with vitamio. If I don't use vitamio It run ok.

Comment: How did you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 4):

It could be because you are not compiling your native code for all platforms. ASUS K012 is running Intel processor and that might be the reason. Add a file called application.mk within your JNI folder and the following parameter
APP_ABI := all

This compiles the native portion for all platforms.